# How to get name of admin folder in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

```
$link= PS_ADMIN_DIR;
$admin_folder = substr(strrchr($link, "\ "), 1);
```

currently i am using this way to get folder name,
But if there are any direct method or any constant please suggest me..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, admin folder name is not stored anywhere in your PrestaShop's files or database, so you have to do something like you do to find it.

However, you should use `_PS_ADMIN_DIR_` instead of `PS_ADMIN_DIR` as the second one is not defined directly by PrestaShop and could be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

To be a little bit more specific : the name of the admin directory is on the filesystem.
When you access a page of the admin directory, a script puts the current directory's path in the _PS_ADMIN_DIR_ constant.

If you forgot the name of the the admin directory you must have a look at the filesystem of your server.

Admin directories are automatically renamed to something like adminXXXX.

If you named it differently you can compare the default directory structure with your actual structure and find the proper directory.

You can also look for files that are only present in the admin directory. The "get-file-admin.php" file for example.

On linux, the following command run from the prestashop root directory will tell you the actual name of the admin directory :

```
find ./ -name get-file-admin.php
```