# Generate admin product route in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I would like to know how to generate the "admin product route" in php using prestashop 1.7.

In my case I got the product id I need and I would like my custom controller redirect me to this given admin product route such as :

`admin/index.php/sell/catalog/products/[id_product]?_token=[token]`

Is there any solution ?

Comment: find id_product variable and token in php code and then assign them to tpl

Comment: But what about the unique "admin" folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Tools::getAdminTokenLite
```

To get a token ([more info here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/2bc8d74c03b88f6f62900c0eae62f99aed26c4c7/classes/Tools.php))

For the admin directory, I gave a tip here: [How to get name of admin folder in prestashop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579426/how-to-get-name-of-admin-folder-in-prestashop/61111391#61111391)

For example use [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) in the root directory of prestashop, then scandir all the directories you find, looking for "get-file-admin.php" or any admin-specific file, and you're done.